# JTextPane losing styling just after the text is displayed

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a thread which functions as follows: characters are continuously entered, which are being stored in a `StringBuilder`. The contents of this string builder need to be styled according to some codes. As the character is appended in the string builder, I have a loop that splits this into an array of strings, and does some processing. Here is small (but complete in itself processing):

```
SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();

if(string.contains(code1)){ 
    str = string;               
    int index = string.indexOf(code1); 
    string = string.replaceAll(code1, "");
    StyleConstants.setForeground(set, Color.GREEN);

    // data is a another variable of string builder
    data.append(string);
    i = sb.indexOf(string);

    String st = string.substring(index); 

    doc.setCharacterAttributes(data.indexOf(st), st.length(), set, true);
}

//similarly there are checks and styling for other codes

//terminalArea is of JTextPane type
terminalArea.setText(dataToShow.toString());
```

The text is colored correctly according to the codes, But as the data is displayed, the colors appear for an instant, and then lost. After that that, when a key is pressed, the colors appear again, but as the key is released, they lost.

I tried `terminalArea.repaint()`, but nothing happens.

**Update:**
With respect to StanislavL's answer, Here is what I am having now:

```
doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
if(string.contains(code)){
        str = string;
        int index = string.indexOf(code); 
        string = string.replaceAll(code, "");
        StyleConstants.setForeground(set, Color.GREEN);
        dataToShow.append(string);
        i = sb.indexOf(string);
        String st = string.substring(index); 
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(dataToShow.indexOf(st), st.length(), set, true);
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength() , string, null);


        }
//after all conditions
terminalArea.setDocument(doc);
```

Though the color persists, but only that text is shown colored, which was colored last. The previous ones are shown in white.Please note, the whole string is not colored, only a part of it is colored.

**Solved:**

StanislavL's answer solved the problem. I overlooked this thing that I was setting the character attributes first, then inserting the array. Interchanging the position solved the issue.

Comment: actually verdsrobert already did and also if you don't like the edit you can always `rollback` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use `StyledEditorKit`.

terminalArea.setText(dataToShow.toString());

The code just erases all you have and readd the text to the document. In fact in the document `remove(0, docLength)` is called and then `insertString(theToStringResult)` replaces all the styled.

I would recomment to create a new `Document` instance, insert all the texts with styled using `insertString()` where you can pass your attributes (or call `insertString()` just once and the call multiple times `setCharacterAttributes()`). After the `Document` instance is ready just call `terminalArea.setDocument(theDocumentInstance);` rather than `setText()`;

Comment: I am creating the document instance at the beginning of these conditions, then used `setCharacterAttributes()` as before, and then in the end used `terminalArea.setDocument(doc)`. Though the color persists, but only that text is shown colored, which was colored last. The previous ones are shown in white.Please note, the whole string is not colored, only a part of it is colored.

Comment: Post SSCCE to illustrate the problem

Comment: Even if I created that example, I fear it willn't be short .

Comment: In the posted code you should either call insertString() passing the set OR insert all the text just once and setCharacterAttributes() for desired fragments. Not both!

Comment: If I pass the set in `insertString()`, then whole string is colored, and I need to color only a substring of that big string.

Comment: you should not insert the whole string just once but multiple inserts of fragments each with own set. Or use insertString() just once and color it fragment by fragment using setCharacterAttributes(). And then call setDocument() (not setText())